# Change classpath after build with Ant

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have a client, server, and client+server build files. Here they are:
[Client](http://pastebin.com/aNFk3QKF)
[Server](http://pastebin.com/WxKiwLVg)
[Client+Server](http://pastebin.com/5MjAfb5U)

**Edit**: Just to make it completely clear, the only file I'm having a problem with right now is the `Server`. I only included the others to show how they are linked, but they are unnecessary to look at.

The problem I'm having is with the server. I am bundling all the libraries with the server ear, but when the classpath is made the relative location of the libraries is `../`. I need this to be `../../`. If I do a build where I pathconvert the classpath to `../../`, then it can't find the libraries because it isn't in that location until after the build.

Can I somehow make this ant build change the classpath once the jar is made? (I realize this is unlikely)

Or are there any better ways to handle this before the build so that I can get the classpath correct?

Per request, here is the part I am concerned with. Specifically the `server.package` and `server.app_package` targets. The libraries are bundled in the ear. So to get at them the classpath needs to be `../../`.

```
  <project name="GPServer" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>

    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <dirname property="server.basedir" file="${ant.file.GPServer}"/>
  <property name="server.src" location="${server.basedir}/src"/>
  <property name="server.build" location="${server.basedir}/build"/>
  <property name="server.dist"  location="${server.basedir}/dist"/>
  <property name="server.lib"  location="${server.basedir}/lib"/>
  <property name="deploy.location"  location="${server.basedir}/../../jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments"/>
  <property name="jboss.lib" location="${server.basedir}/../../jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/lib"/>

    <path id="server.class.path">
      <!-- <fileset dir="${server.basedir}/lib">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset> -->
      <fileset dir="${server.lib}">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${server.basedir}">
          <include name="*.properties"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>

    <pathconvert property="server.modified.class.path" refid="server.class.path">
        <globmapper from="../*" to="../../*" />
    </pathconvert>

    <path id="final.server.classpath">
        <pathelement path="${server.modified.class.path}"/>
    </path>


  <target name="server.init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${server.build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${server.dist}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="server.compile" depends="server.init" description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${dist} -->
    <javac srcdir="${server.src}" destdir="${server.dist}" >
        <classpath>
            <path refid="final.server.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="server.package" depends="server.compile" description="create the jar" >
        <manifestclasspath property="manifest.path" jarfile="${server.dist}/GrahamsProjServer.jar">
            <classpath refid="final.server.classpath"/>
        </manifestclasspath>
        <jar destfile="${server.dist}/GrahamsProjServer.jar" basedir="${server.dist}" excludes="*.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.path}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="server.app_package" depends="server.package" description="create the jar" >
    <ear destfile="${server.dist}/GrahamsProjServer.ear" appxml="${server.basedir}/META-INF/application.xml" >
        <metainf dir="${server.basedir}/META-INF"/>
        <fileset dir="${server.dist}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${server.basedir}" includes="lib/*.jar" />
    </ear>
  </target>

  <target name="server.deploy" depends="server.package" description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <ear destfile="${deploy.location}/GrahamsProjServer.ear" appxml="${server.basedir}/META-INF/application.xml" >
        <metainf dir="${server.basedir}/META-INF"/>
        <fileset dir="${server.dist}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${server.basedir}" includes="lib/*.jar" />
    </ear>
  </target>



  <target name="server.clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${server.build}"/>
    <delete dir="${server.dist}"/>
    <echo message="Deleting files in ${deploy.location}"/>
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="${deploy.location}" excludes="*.txt"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Which target(s) are you calling and in which order ?

Comment: Please include the code fragment that is a concern for you.  In a couple of month the links will become 404's.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you IMPORT your subscripts in `client+server`.

```
<!-- ============================================= -->
<!--       Import Server/Client Build Files        -->
<!-- ============================================= -->
<import file="${basedir}/../GrahamsProjClient/build-client.xml"/>
<import file="${basedir}/../GrahamsProjServer/build-server.xml"/>
```

You should not do that.  If you want to execute targets in a separate build file, use `<ant>` task for that -> http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

Comment: The problem is happening in the `server` ant file. Not the `client+server` ant file. Sorry I should have made that more clear. In fact there was really no reason for me to even include the `client` and `client+server` ant files.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I'm using java webstart. I don't have to have the libraries in the manifest at all. They only need to be in the webstart's jnlp file.